# Android notifyDatasetChange with SQLite cursor how to?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-adapter

So I have 2 activities.

The first (ActivityOne) displays a listview with data from SQLite cursor, and a button.
On click of that button, I want to add an item to the listview, so I display the second activity (ActivityTwo), that contains a number of editTexts and a save Button, that does the saving in the Database.

**But what I want is**:

after saving the new item to the DB, the ActivityTwo should close and    the ActivityOne should be displayed with the refreshed content from    the DB

.
This seems a reasonable workflow. How do I achieve it?
Code for ActivityOne:

```
public class ActivityOne extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<String> idclient = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> numeclient = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> tipclient = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_clienti);
        LoadList();

        Button btnex = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewCli);
        btnex.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View aView)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Add new client... " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent toAnotherActivity = new Intent(aView.getContext(), NewClientActivity.class);
                        startActivity(toAnotherActivity);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

 public void LoadList(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = new myDbHelper(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("select idclient,nameclient,typeclient from clienti order by numeclient" , null);
        idclient.clear();
        numeclient.clear();
        tipclient.clear();

        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                idclient.add(Integer.toString(mCursor.getInt(0)));
                nameclient.add(mCursor.getString(1));
                typeclient.add(mCursor.getString(2));
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        DisplayClientiAdapter disadpt = new DisplayClientiAdapter(ClientiActivity.this,idclient,nameclient, typeclient);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_clienti);
        lv.setAdapter(disadpt);
        mCursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

And in the ActivityTwo, I have in a button click:

```
db.execSQL("insert into clients (idclient, nameclient,typeclient,...");
DisplayClientiAdapter da = new DisplayClientiAdapter(getApplicationContext());
da.notifyDataSetChanged();
finish();
```

Also the displayAdapter is something like:

```
public class DisplayClientiAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> idclient;
    private ArrayList<String> numeclient;
    private ArrayList<String> tipclient;

    public DisplayClientiAdapter(Context c){
        this.mContext = c;
    }

    public DisplayClientiAdapter(Context c,  ArrayList<String> idclient, ArrayList<String> numeclient, ArrayList<String> tipclient) {
        this.mContext = c;
        this.idclient = idclient;
        this.numeclient = numeclient;
        this.tipclient = tipclient;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return idclient.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder mHolder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        if (child == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.clienti_item, null);
            mHolder = new Holder();
            mHolder.txt_idclient = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.tv_cl_id);
            mHolder.txt_numeclient = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.tv_cl_nume);
            mHolder.txt_tipclient = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.tv_cl_tip);
            child.setTag(mHolder);
        } else {
            mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }
        mHolder.txt_idclient.setText(idclient.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_numeclient.setText(numeclient.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_tipclient.setText(tipclient.get(pos));
        return child;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView txt_idclient;
        TextView txt_numeclient;
        TextView txt_tipclient;
    }
```

Of course it does not work like this. The list is not refreshed... I assume it has to do with the displayAdapter !?!?!
I cannot call the LoadList method since it is static or something like that...

Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a problem with your adapter. You have to call Loadlist() in onresume method instead of oncreate method in ActivityOne. It will work then.

Comment: Thanks. You were right. I moved it to onResume and it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have a look at this two articles:

http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/

You shouldn't inflate your views with `null` in your inflate method if you have parent view available.
Also, using application context for inflating may cause strange behaviour, as it may not use correct theme you may've set in app manifest for your `Activity`.

On the other hand - why don't you use [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) instead of `BaseAdapter`?

The problem with your adapter is, that you don't set the data in it! :)

///EDIT:
I checked the wrong activity - why do you create second adapter in there?

The easiest solution would be to move the LoadList() to `onStart`.

If you want to do it right, you should use `ContentObserver` and (probably) `CursorAdapter`.

Comment: I do not use other approaches because this approach works. I only had to move the LoadList() from onCreate to onResume and everything works just fine